# Why can't I get the checkout state of SharePoint documents checked out by all users with Micosoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

Since the Graph documentation indicates that the publication facet is available in v1.0, I'd like to report that it is not possible to get all checked out files in group/SharePoint sites. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/publicationfacet?view=graph-rest-1.0

Use case: our customers would like to know which group files in their Office 365 tenant have been checked out (by who - would be great - for another time).

**It's not possible to get this global picture with requests made with Graph API:**

```
GET /v1.0/drives/driveID/root/children?$select=name,publication
```

- Using delegated permissions, I'm only able to see the 'checkout'
  value for files I have checked out myself. All other files checked
  out by others appear as 'published'.
- Using app permissions, I'm only able to see the 'checkout' value for
  files checked out by apps, any apps (checkout using Graph API beta).

Here's an image of the various checkout scenarios as seen in SharePoint, and then in our Graph-based app with different authentications (values verified in Postman).
[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQFYS.jpg)

Comment: You might be able to get this from the SharePoint side using `/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}/fields/$expand=CheckoutUser`.

Comment: Thanks for the info Marc - I see them all :) it's too bad we can't get that directly at the drive item level.

Comment: I suspect this issue is due to check in/out still being in beta. You might be able to use the beta API to see `publication`.

Comment: Still get the same result with GET /beta/drives/driveID/root/children?$select=name,publication. Guess we'll build a workaround for now. Thanks again!

Comment: @MarcLaFleur This issue still exists after 3 years. Is there any way to get the `publication` status at the driveItem level?